# Count total rows ignoring the select limit

Tags: mysql, select, count

I want to make a select in MySQL having limit of rows, but in the same select to count the total number of rows (not between limits).

How can I alter the code bellow to count all rows from that products table? If I add a count in this select it will count only 10.

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        categ 
FROM    products

LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: `If I add a count in this select it will count only 10.` what sql do you mean here? Please edit the question to show the query, and the result.

Comment: You are not counting anything anywhere in your SQL. Where is `COUNT(1)`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
SELECT  id,name,categ ,( SELECT count(*)
FROM products) as numberRows FROM products
LIMIT 10
```

there is an example :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccc90496f13be1cc046b72cd9078c080

Comment: SELECT  id,name,categ ,( SELECT count(*)
 FROM products) as numberRows FROM products
 LIMIT 10

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ccc90496f13be1cc046b72cd9078c080

Comment: Thanks. I need this to create a select from pagination.
So it's better to use your select or to make a select like below:

SELECT  * FROM  products;
Stock number of rows with mysqli_num_rows.

Having number of rows create another select to limit number of products per page
SELECT  id,name,categ FROM products LIMIT 0, 10";

I don't know witch it's the corect one.